# Does dynamic biding only happen with object on heap in C++?

Tags: c++

Will dynamic binding happen with the object on stack?

For example

f() is a virtual function in both Base and Derived

```
int main(){

  Derived d1;
  Based *b= new Derived();

  d1.f();
  b->f();
}
```

Comment: Note that `d1.f()` may be statically dispatched.  The reason why is that the compiler 'knows' the type of `d1` so can optimize out the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: b->f() can also be statically dispatched here, because the compiler again knows the exact type, but the call starts out as virtual dispatch and determining the exact function at compile time is an optimization.  Only pointers and references are polymorphic, member function calls on a local object are always static.  And polymorphic calls use v-table binding which is not the same as dynamic binding.

Answer (score 6):

Virtual functions work for both heap and stack objects.  Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
    virtual void doit()
    {
        std::cout << "base::doit" << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    virtual void doit()
    {
        std::cout << "derived::doit" << std::endl;
    }
};

void invokevirtual(base &b)
{
    b.doit();
}

int main()
{
    derived d;
    invokevirtual(d);
}
```

Comment: so you what's the output? I have no compiler right now. I can't see.  If the output is "derived::doit", that's what you mean dynamic binding?

Comment: @skydoor - the output is "derived::doit" because virtual functions work for all objects regardless of where they are allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Sorry for the short answer, but you seem to know what is happening and just needed some confirmation, right?